# Using Angular to update content/data in Wordpress?

Tags: angularjs, wordpress

I need help to understand what is wrong here, for example I have the following:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
    params: {
        action: "update_something_really_cool",
        user_data: "---- :D "
    }
}).success(function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

This will out return at the console:

`Object{'user_data': null}`

The http request is made that way since styles like:

```
$http.post
$http.get
```

returns `0` which means the action is not being triggered.

At wordpress level I have this:

```
function update_something_really_cool(){
    $user_data = $_POST['user_data'];
    echo json_encode(array('user_data' => $user_data));
    exit();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_update_something_really_cool', 'update_something_really_cool' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_update_something_really_cool', 'update_something_really_cool' );
```

I try using the `$.param` but still same result...

Also try using different headers:

```
headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'},
```

does any one know how to do this? I have no problem doing this with other actions, but when I need to pass something else besides the action parameter.. :(

Comment: userdata vs user_data? Something is funny there.

Comment: @MathewBerg just a miss spelled while doing the dummy code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the only solution that did work is this:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
    data: $.param({
        action: 'update_something_really_cool',
        user_data: data // object {key:value}
    }),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
}).success(function(data){
    console.log(data);
    //outputs the sent opbject
});
```

For some reason `$.param` didn't pass the right values before.. but this solution did work while ordered in this way... I hope it can help some one ;)